# 'From/import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, windows-10, anaconda

I'm having trouble importing Machine Learning algorithms from scikit-learn.
 I have it installed but whenever I type for example "from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB" it says " 'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
 I'm using Anaconda on Windows 10. Is it compatibility issue? Am I missing something? Idk I'm still new to Python so I feel lost. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to write the Import command in the Python terminal. You can activate the Python terminal using the "Python" command.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That needs to be run in the Python REPL, not at a command line. Be sure to start one before typing Python statements.

Comment: IPython is a Python REPL, so I would not be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Internal or External command can be solved but just 3 steps:
(Before doing make sure you undo all hidden apps)

1. Select the path of the scripts which are there in your local computer (eg. C drive--> users --> (a file with your name) --> AppData --> Local --> then while you go forward you find Scripts.
2. Copy that Path.
3. Open edit the system environment variables--> go to path --> add new --> paste the copied Scripts path and click ok. Close all the prompts and run again.

It worked for me