# Command Prompt does not work with Canopy nor Conda

Tags: python, prompt, conda, canopy

Last night I tried to install a Py package via conda install and it required conda update. I accepted, got an error and now just can't use Conda prompt command. I removed, reinstalled and even tried to use Canopy prompt, but nothing. I'm considering to try miniconda, but not sure if it will work.

When I open cmd, for both Conda and Canopy, it appears like:

```
(User) C:\Users\my_user
```

If I try to import a package, for instance, I get:

```
"import" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I think that it's probably a PATH issue, but I don't know to deal with it. I use Python34.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by this?: "now just can't use prompt command."

Comment: If you can open a command prompt window, what is the output (text, not screen shot) of the command `set` ?

Comment: I mean that, for instance conda cmd, it doesn't recognize packages, or regular commands.. Windows pmpt is fine. Let me edit to avoid misunderstands.

Comment: When I try to import a package:

"import" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['From/import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311877/from-import-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to type a Python command (`import`) at a Windows command prompt, where it is not defined, and so not expected to work. Type `ipython` first to open a Python prompt, where `import` is a valid command.