# Installed tensorflow in one environment, now import doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So, I installed tensorflow in one environment in Jupyter, and now I can't import anything, even unrelated modules like pandas. The thing is I don't use tensorflow, but need it as backend for keras. When I want to import any module, I receive this error.

Edit: In Jupyter, it takes an indefinite amount of time to start the kernel in tensorflow environment. Basically, I can't run any command, even assign a variable. Assigning variables work in a non-tensorflow environment, but again I can't import any module, say even pandas.

```
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If there's anyway to install the three libraries, I'd be happy to know. Thank you all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['From/import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311877/from-import-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

Comment: I edited. Can you please remove the yellow tag? The other thread does not answer my question.

Comment: Can you please explain why that does not answer your question? Awkwardly enough, I think a screenshot of your typed command and the error could provide an evidence.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The key point is that during the installation, a new environment should not be defined for tensorflow. I just installed all the libraries with pip command. And it works.