# In Anaconda prompt 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda 4.7.12 in Windows 10. However, the import command is not recognized. I get the error message as shown below in the image. I did some research and found that the majority of the solutions suggest to add the Ananconda directory as the system environment variables. Hence I did that. But still no luck. Any help will be appreciated. The details of the Anaconda version and the python version can be found in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['From/import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311877/from-import-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-pro)

Answer (score 2):

`import` is a Python statement. You're in the command prompt. Type `python` and press `enter`, then try again.

Comment: `import` is a statement and not a function but your answer is still useful to solve OP's problem.

Comment: Good observation. Edited.